# Save running instance of pdf into different location

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am getting the running instance of microsoft word document and saving it in different location using `Microsoft.Interop.Word` library with the SaveAs.

Similary I need to get the running process of adobe reader and need to save in differnt location. Is that supported with `Microsoft.Interop`.

```
app = (Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
Word.Document doc;
doc = app.ActiveDocument;
doc.SaveAs(@"c:\test.doc");
```

Any ideas?

Update:

Is there a way to find running instance of AcroRd32.exe and save the file to a different location with c# code?

Answer (score -1):

> Similary I need to get the running process of adobe reader and need to save in differnt location. Is that supported with Microsoft.Interop.

No, it is not supported. Adobe Reader is not a part of Microsoft Office.

The OLE automation interface is only provided by Adobe Acrobat, not Adobe Reader.

For a complete reference of Acrobat's automation API, see the "OLE Automation" section of [this document](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf). Also you may find the [Developing for Adobe Reader](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/reader_overview.pdf) document helpful.

Comment: do we need to invoke acrodr32.exe through c# and save the pdf?

Comment: Yes, but to be able to automate the process you need to have Adobe Acrobat installed. Adobe Reader doesn't provide OLE automation interfaces.

Comment: Take a look at the links I mentioned in my post.